# detecting collisions and destroying gameObjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm attempting to create a 2D game in Unity where the gameObjects would be destroyed upon hitting the walls. So i decided to use the isTrigger function and add the script to each of the walls. However, I do not know why the gameObjects don't get destroyed. I have tried to set Collision type as both discrete and continuous for the walls and gameobjects and I've also added static rigidbodys to the walls to see if that would help and even tried changing the size of the collisionbodys of the walls.

Here is the code for the wallscript

```
public class wallScript : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


public void OnTrigger2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.tag == "player01")
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }

}}
```

p.s. Even if I remove the conditional statement Destroy() still does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {...}` instead of `void OnTrigger2D(Collider2D other)`.
And uncheck `Is Trigger` checkbox on your object's Collider.

Comment: Thank you, your method worked for me! but I don't understand why the isTrigger2D doesn't work.

Comment: Because Trigger is: when objects intersect each other like (one enter to another); Collision is: when objects make contact (like they are touching each other, but not intersect).

If my answer helped you, please, mark as solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stack overflow; but if I mark objects as istrigger doesn't that mean they intersect each other so they should be destroyed?

Comment: IsTrigger can be used for areas. In case a player crosses the boundary (or enters) this area, any script can be run. There is no need to use a collider. And neither the player nor the area would be destroyed, if you don't destroy them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To Fix The Problem You Are Facing, First Select The Wall Sprite In The Scene, Scroll Down To The Collider And Make Sure **Is Trigger** Is Checked.

Other Than That Just Check If The Tag You Typed Into The Code Matches The Player You Are Trying To Destroy. Remember, It's Case Sensitive!

After That The Code Should Run Just Fine.

Comment: I did but my code still didn't work for some reason, OnCollisionEnter2D worked tho